# Выборка между датами

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с данными. В таблице есть два поля: start и expire. Оба timestamp. Никак не могу докумекать как сделать выборку за определенный период (вводим две даты как timestampы), переданный через запрос. Просьба помочь. Заранее спасибо!

Таблица вида:

```
id = 123
name = Акция
startdate = 1338494400
enddate = 1340827200
```

Допустим, хочу я получить акции, действительные с 1 января 2011 (1325365200) по 30 января (1327870800). Как сформировать запрос?

Comment: @SmartTry, Следует править вопрос, а не добавлять данные в комментарии. В этом случае данные выглядит более структурировано.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Все события, которые **начались** в промежуткок времени ( Точка принадлежит отрезку )

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start BETWEEN @ts1 AND @ts2
```

2) Все события, которые **начались И закончились** в промежутке времени ( Отрезок лежит в отрезке)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start > @ts1 AND expire < @ts2
```

3) Все события, которые **проходили** в промежутке времени ( Отрезок пересекает отрезок )

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start < @ts2 AND expire > @ts1
```

Заменить `table` - на имя таблицы, `@ts1` - на TimeStamp1, `@ts2` - на TimeStamp2

Comment: Мм, не получается так(
Дополнил комментарием вопрос с пояснением.

Comment: Вам привели просто шикарный ответ, вы тыкнули разок sql запрос, потом пишите не получается...

Я так понимаю вы ожидаете великого экстрасенса который поймет что именно вы сделали не так и сделает все за вас дабы вы могли скопипастить, проверить - работает, вау, класс - я крутой программист !111АДИН!

Эх, во что превращается веб... Я очень недавно в этой сфере и с каждым днем мне становится все грустнее и грустнее т.к. примеры подобного рода, к моему великому сожалению - не единичны, а, скорее, несут массовый характер.

Comment: жесть, я уже устал такие комменты писать... нужно минусовать юзеров и при минус 10 в бан его на неделю.